Contradictions in "A diagonalizable energy-momentum tensor $T$ satisfies the SEC iff $\rho + p_1+p_2+p_3 \ge 0$ and $\rho + p_i ≥ 0 (i = 1, 2, 3)$
I am trying to understand the prove of this proposition
:
Let $T$ be a diagonalizable energy-momentum tensor, that is, (T_{µν}) = diag$(\rho, p_1, p_2, p_3)$ on some orthonormal frame $\{E_0, E_1, E_2, E_3\}$. Show that $T$ satisfies the strong energy condition (SEC) if and only if
$\rho + p_1+p_2+p_3  \ge 0$ and $\rho + p_i ≥ 0 (i = 1, 2, 3)$
I found the proof in this thesis  https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/10653663.-pdf where the definition of strong energy condition is

and the proof of the theorem as given in this document on page 17, theorem 1.5.2: (where Segrè type just means diagonal $T_{\mu\nu}=$diag$(\rho,p_1,p_2,p_3)$) and where they are using  the equivalent formulation so, a future directed timelike unit vector (which is said to be equivalent that using just a timelike  vector)

Notice also the definition  
I went to the reference they provide for the proof (Eric Poisson- a Relativistic's toolkit the mathematics of black -hole mechanics), and found some apparently contradictory arguments  and definitions. I would appreciate someone clear up why these point to me.
This is the prove in Poisson's book:


How is Poisson concluding that $\rho + p_1 + p_2 + p_3 \ge a^2(p_2+p_3 -\rho-p_1)\implies \rho +p_1\ge 0$ ?

Besides Poisson argues that we must have $a^2<1$, why is that?
In the thesis they take the limit for $a\to \infty$ instead , so here that condition is not imposed. An besides since in Lorentizian manifolds we have a signature -+++, I guess a unit vector doesn't have to have its components less that 1, since the (-) sign allows to have components greater than 1 and get a  norm =1 anyway. So I don't underderstand where Poisson gets that condition from.

Why  is Poisson assuming that the vector $v^\alpha$ given by equation 2.4 has that form with the $\gamma$ factor in the front? and not a generic  timelike future directed vector as in the thesis?

In the thesis, why is $FT_P$   the set of normalized future-directed timelike vector? If I attempt to compute the norm I should get -1, but this depends on the metric which should be generic:


$\|\hat v^{\mu}e_{\mu}\|=g_{\mu\nu}\hat v^{\mu}\hat v^{\nu}=....=-1??$
However if I assumed the metric is the Minkowski metric diag(-1,1,1,1)then it is clear that
$\|\hat v^{\mu}e_{\mu}\|=g_{\mu\nu}\hat v^{\mu}\hat v^{\nu}= -(1+a^2+b^2+c^2)+a^2+b^2+c^2=-1$, so it is unit timelike
